# Google SpeechToText API: no text in response from OGG Opus audio streaming

Tags: javascript, google-speech-api, ogg, google-cloud-speech, opus

I'm using the [SpeechToText API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/) to get a speech transcription from a live microphone recording. This is working well with a simple LINEAR16 encoding but I need to reduce the bandwidth so I switched to an OGG Opus encoding.
The audio is recorded and encoded in OGG Opus client-side, using [this library](https://github.com/chris-rudmin/opus-recorder).
Then, it's sent to a backend app using a websocket.
Finally, the backend app requests the STT API in streaming mode, which stays silent (no error but also no text in output).

These are the options for the encoding:

```js
var options = {
    monitorGain: 0,
    recordingGain: 1,
    numberOfChannels: 1,
    encoderSampleRate: 16000,
    encoderPath: "./javascript/ogg_opus/encoderWorker.min.js",
    originalSampleRateOverride: 16000,
    streamPages: true,
    encoderApplication: 2048
};
```

This is the configuration which is sent to the API:

```js
{
   encoding: 'OGG_OPUS',
   language: 'fr',
   rate: 16000
}
```

This is the way the audio is sent to the websocket:

```js
recorder.ondataavailable = function(typedArray){
    var dataBlob = new Blob([typedArray], { type: 'audio/ogg' });
    websocket.emit('audio_data', dataBlob);
};
```

The backend part is developed in Python, following this [example](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize).

Do you know the OGG Opus configuration needed to get the API to work?

Comment: A few things: first, it should really be language --> language_code and rate --> sample_rate_hertz (but you should get an error). Second, you should test a generated file with the Text-to-speech API, in synchronous mode and see if that works (it should). And finally, do you really need to use the streaming API + Audio stream vs. simply using a file or even the Synchronous API? Bottom line I don't think the problem is with the configuration of the API calls.